# Why do matrix brackets look strange when using package unicode-math?

Tags: matrices, typography, unicode-math

Compare this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    e & f \\
    g & h
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

to this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    e & f \\
    g & h
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The brackets generated with `unicode-math` don't look as clean. You can clearly see the joints of different bracket components.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That is a viewer-dependent issue. Your pdf viewer sees one line behind the other and uses some heuristics to draw them a tad wider when the lines overlap. This should not show up in the printed document.

Comment: I have the same problem, and my printed version shows the same ugly braces...

Comment: @Harald you should post your own question instead of commenting on such an old question